# Processing a continuous single line of data with stream processing in bash pipeline?

Tags: text-processing, sed, pipe, stdin, tr

I am debugging an embedded server that outputs a continuous single line of text to a specified network port. There is no newline anywhere in the stream but it is text data and I would like to format it as it outputs. I have tried using tr (translate) to swap a character in the stream for a newline which works, however it is impossible to find a unique single character that can always be sensibly replaced by a newline. My initial thought was to use sed to add a newline character to a pattern of 2-3 characters but because sed is line based and the stream is a never ending single line, sed will never complete the process! Is there a non line based sed alternative?

Comment: Regarding `There is no newline anywhere in the stream but it is text data` - the POSIX definition of text is that it contains newlines so YMMV trying to run text processing tools on it. Many versions of tools like sed, awk, grep, etc. will work probably fine but don't rule out the possibility of a failure due to that input format not really being text per the POSIX definition.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to provide some concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Comment: @EdMorton try `head -c 15000 /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9` for example. That kind of thing isn't really easy to add to a question.

Comment: @terdon the OP said they have specific strings of 2-3 chars (which appears now to be `[15`) they want to split the input at so generating random text wouldn't produce realistic sample input, best I can tell.

Comment: @EdMorton not sure where you get that from: "*however it is impossible to find a unique single character that can always be sensibly replaced by a newline*". Presumably they later found that the string `[15` works, but the whole question is about just inserting newlines to be able to process the text so missing the odd `[15` cause it's been split is unlikely to be a problem. But yes, only the OP can tell us for sure.

Comment: The OP said `My initial thought was to use sed to add a newline character to a pattern of 2-3 characters` and in the answer the OP posted they're calling `fold` and THEN splitting at `[15`s and then removing the newlines that `fold` had added which IMO they wouldn't be doing if the whole question is about just inserting newlines - those `[15`s seem to be important. Over to the OP to tell us what they really need...

Comment: Apologies if you were eager for more information however the solution I posted worked for my purposes. @terdon point was correct, it is less a formatting problem and more a usability of data problem. The pattern [15 occurs as a sort of header for the data so to make it easier to break up I decided to re-add the newlines in front of this pattern, however that is by the by. The key point of the question relates to breaking up data for processing which the fold method does well. Any additional information is ancillary. I added a portion of the final command purely for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution worked out as

```
stdbuf -o0 ncat -ul 51002 | stdbuf -o0 fold | sed "s/\[15/\&\[15/g" -u | stdbuf -o0 tr -d '\n' | tr "&" "\n"
```

Where [15 was the pattern I wanted to prepend a newline to. A bit of a workaround but it worked well.

Comment: Excellent :-) Please don't forget to drop by to accept the answer after 48 hours so this gets marked resolved and becomes useful for others facing similar issue.

Comment: You didn't explain *why* you want a newline in the output, or what you want to achieve, but I wonder whether piping into `hexdump -C` wouldn't do as well.

Comment: @U.Windl I explained this in the original question. I don't think the reason why I need the data in that format is all that relevant but if you must know I have an embedded network device that spits large quantities of debug information onto a port in a continuous stream. The information is ascii but it provides some specific lines of hex that I want to filter out and translate into ASCII. The newlines make this much simpler

Comment: If you just want to insert a newline before every `[15`, why all those pipes and commands instead of just `stdbuf -o0 ncat -ul 51002 | sed 's/\[15/\n&/g'`? Your command line seems to be adding newlines using `fold` (which could change a `[15` into `[1\n5]` or similar btw), then adding `&`s, then removing the newlines that `fold` added (so why add them in the first place?), then converting the `&`s that sed added and any `&`s that were present in the original input to newlines. Seems overly complicated and fragile.

Comment: @EdMorton as I mentioned in the initial post, sed is line based. My content is coming in as a single line of never ending data. If I pipe this directly into sed it will simply never finish substituting.

Comment: OK, but as far as I understand your requirements you still can't do what you're doing in this answer for the reasons I mentioned. Edit your question to update your requirements to cover the currently missing information about needing to split the line at every `[15` and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: You mentioned `If I pipe this directly into sed it will simply never finish substituting.` as a problem - given an unending input stream, when do you WANT sed (or whatever other tool) to stop substituting?

Comment: @EdMorton your point regarding fold breaking up the line terminator is valid. I believe I can fix this using the `fold -s` option I will add it to my answer. As for your question regarding when do I want to stop substituting, I may have been ambiguous in my response. What I meant was, sed will never output a processed line because it doesn't register a newline. My goal is to do a series of filters and translations on a data stream, the addition of newlines simply makes this much easier

Comment: From everything you've said so far there's much easier ways of doing what you're trying to do than what's in your answer - if you show sample input and expected output in your question we can help you. Good luck either way.

Answer (score 5):

That's what `fold` is for:

```
NAME
       fold - wrap each input line to fit in specified width

SYNOPSIS
       fold [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Wrap input lines in each FILE, writing to standard output.

       With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

       Mandatory  arguments  to  long options are mandatory for short options
       too.

       -b, --bytes
              count bytes rather than columns

       -s, --spaces
              break at spaces

       -w, --width=WIDTH
              use WIDTH columns instead of 80

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit
```

As you can see above, it can fold the line based on width so you get lines of 100 characters with:

```
command_that_reads_from_port | fold -w 100
```

This is a standard program, part of GNU coreutils, so it should be present on any GNU system.

Comment: This was great! Not perfect but it helped me find my solution:
`stdbuf -o0 ncat -ul 51002 | stdbuf -o0 fold | sed "s/\[15/\&\[15/g" -u | stdbuf -o0 tr -d '\n' | tr '&' '\n'` where the pattern I was using for a newline was [15

Comment: @stmfunk Then you may want to add this as your own answer.

Comment: @stmfunk yes, please post your answer and accept it. I thought of including `stdbuf` but in my test input (`head -c 1000 /dev/urandom`) it didn't seem to be necessary so I left it out.

Comment: `fold` can/will split `[15`s strings (which the OP has now told us they want to prepend with newlines) depending on where they occur in the input.

Comment: @EdMorton I think those are just random strings that happen to occur regularly enough to be useful as line break markers, not that there's anything special about them or that it would matter if any were missed. So it isn't that they need to split _at_ `[15`, they just want to insert newlines to be able to handle the stream better and `[15` is as good a place as any.

Comment: Maybe but how does it help to take away the ability to find those strings by sometimes putting newlines in the middle of them as `fold` would do? I'd really like the OP to update their question with some clearer requirements and sample input/output.

Answer (score 2):

From the answer you posted it sounds like this might be what you need, using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ printf '%s' 'foo[15bar[15and stuff' |
    awk -v RS='[[]15' '{print pRT $0; pRT=RT}'
foo
[15bar
[15and stuff
```

but without sample input/output it's a guess. You can probably do whatever processing of the data you like inside the awk script, and/or if you want it to stop processing the data after some number of `[15`-separated records or some number of characters you can trivially add a count and exit, e.g. to exit after 20 records:

```
awk -v RS='[[]15' '{print pRT $0; pRT=RT} NR==20{exit}'
```

or after 1000 characters:

```
awk -v RS='[[]15' '{$0=pRT $0; n+=length(); print; pRT=RT} n==1000{exit}'
```

or whatever else you like.

Add the stdbuf parts as needed.